# ajax not work in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

i use `stock gem` to search name of company and return `last-price`.when add Ajax not return any things. no error in console but when open network appear message `failed to load data` .

`stock_controller.rb`

```
    def search
    if params[:stock].present?
        @stock = Stock.new_form_lookup(params[:stock])
        if @stack 
            respond_to do |format|
              format.js { render partial: 'users/result' }
            end
        else
            flash[:danger] = "You have entered an incorrect symbol"
            redirect_to my_portfolio_path
        end

    else
        flash[:danger] = "You have entered an empty search string"
        redirect_to my_portfolio_path
    end
end
```

`my_portfolio.html.erb`

```
 <h1>My Portfolio</h1>

<h3>Search for Stocks</h3>
<div id="stock-lookup">
  <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id:"stock-lookup-form" do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock Ticker Symbol", autofocus: true, class: "form-control search-box input-lg" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success") do %>
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Look up a stock
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div id="results">
  <%= render 'result' %>
</div>
```

`_result.html.erb`

```
<% if @stock%>
    <div class="well result-block">
        <strong>Symbol:</strong> <%= @stock.ticker%>
        <strong>Name:</strong> <%= @stock.name%>
        <strong>Price:</strong> <%= @stock.last_price%>

    </div>
<%end%>
```

`_result.js.erb`

```
$("#results").html("<%= j(render 'users/result.html') %>");
```

when test file `_result.js.erb` add `alert("hello");` work correctly.

setp of add ajax

- add remote: true in form
- add JQuery in application.js
- use format.js and partial:
- create file _result.js.erb

`stock model`

```
    def self.new_form_lookup(ticker_symbol)
    begin

        looked_up_stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker_symbol)
        #price = strip_commas(looked_up_stock.latest_price) 
        new(name: looked_up_stock.company_name, 
            ticker: looked_up_stock.symbol, last_price: looked_up_stock.latest_price)

    rescue Exception => e 
        return nil
    end
end
```

log of output

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06lAp.png)

Comment: Where is `@stack` instantiated?

Comment: Look at your log instead of the browser console. That would be more helpful.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio add model of stock can view please

Comment: @Leo this appear `  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "stock"=>"GOOG", "button"=>""}`

Comment: where do you instantiate `@stack`?

Comment: in `_result.html.erb`?

Answer (score 0):

where do you find `@stack` ?

you only `respond` with `js` if `@stack` is not `nil`

what is the value of `@stack` and where does it get that value?

```
def search
if params[:stock].present?
    @stock = Stock.new_form_lookup(params[:stock])
    if @stack 
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render partial: 'users/result' }
        end
    else
        flash[:danger] = "You have entered an incorrect symbol"
        redirect_to my_portfolio_path
    end

else
    flash[:danger] = "You have entered an empty search string"
    redirect_to my_portfolio_path
end
```